# How to access a wordpress plugin page or add posts without doing it from the Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, dashboard

I am a creating a website on WordPress that uses a plunging called H5P which allows the creation of interactive content. as in the picture below. However the creation of the content is currently only possible from the dashboard. I would like to allow my website guests to use the plugin to create content but from a separate page and without letting them access or use the WordPress dashboard. In other words, I just want to show the users the section in green in the picture. Similarly, Is there any way to allow the guests to create posts also without going from the dashboard? such as another page that the same fields to create a post but to be visited without going through WordPress dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out different plugins like "User Submitted Posts", "WP User Frontend", "ACF Frontend" or similar.

Comment: could you please specify which of the plugins directly helps in the problem explained in the question please?
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't give you a better idea. Try, for example, "WP User Frontend". Try to create a post form in this plugin that is suitable for your task. See how closely you can customize it for your project. In plugins, there are restrictions on configuration and you have to modify something in other ways - custom css, shortcodes, php code, or slightly changing your project, etc. In such plugins, you usually configure which categories of users can create posts, including guests.